# searching for a file in a network drive using recursion.prblm:no such file or directory after 2 steps

Tags: perl

I have a network folder in which i have to search for a file and get the complete path for that particular file.
i have tried to implement using recursion.

```
use dirsearch;
use Cwd;
$dir = "\\\\moon\\builds502\\TEST\\Q1105ASRAWBF100044";
$filename="oncrpc_prot.c";
$path=dirsearch->search($dir,$filename);
print "path of $filename :: $path";
```

this is the perl script which in turn uses a module which goes  like this

```
package dirsearch;
sub search{
    $arg0=shift;
    $dir=shift;
    $filename=shift;
    print $dir,"\n";
    print $filename,"\n";
    #chdir($dir) or die $!;
    chomp($dir);
    chomp($filename);
    opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;
    while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {
        #Using a regular expression to ignore files beginning with a period
        unless ($file =~ m/^\./){
            if(-d "$dir\\$file"){
                #closedir(DIR);
                $dir=$dir.'\\'.$file;
                print $dir,"\n";
                search($dir,$filename);
            }
            else{
                if($file =~ /$filename/){
                    $path=$dir."\\".$file;
                    #print $path,"\n";
                    return $path;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $str="file not found";
    return $str;
    #closedir(DIR);
}
1;
```

the network path consists of a system of folders and subfolders..after just 2 runs it reaches to the state of "No such file or directory found in diresearch.pm in line 11" though the directory exists.
the output looks like this

```
\\moon\builds502\TEST\Q1105ASRAWBF100044
oncrpc_prot.c
\\moon\builds502\TEST\Q1105ASRAWBF100044\Crm
oncrpc_prot.c

No such file or directory at dirsearch.pm line 11.
```

somebody please help me find out my mistake or anyway to implement my requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `search($dir,$filename);` within the `dirsearch` package, you have to call it as :

```
$arg0->search($dir,$filename);
```

In the `sub search` you're doing:

```
$arg0=shift;
$dir=shift;
$filename=shift;
```

then in the second turn you assign:

```
$arg0 to $dir
$dir to $filename
and then $filename is undef
```

so you get `No such file or directory ...`

And you really must put these two lines at the begining :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```